# if A diagonalizable then show that $a=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $A= \begin{pmatrix}
     2 & 0 & 0\\
     a & 2 & 0 \\
b & c & -1\\
        \end{pmatrix}$
if A diagonalizable then show $a=0$.

$P_A(x)=|xI-A|=(x-2)^2(x+1)=x^3-3x^2+4$

since A diagonalizable there is a P matrix such as $A=P^{-1}DP$

$D= \begin{pmatrix}
     2 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1\\
        \end{pmatrix}$

from cayley hamil. $A^3-3A^2+4I=0$ how do we continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether there are 2 different eigenvectors to $2$. An $2$-eigenvector $v$ satisfies 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
a & 0 & 0 \\
b & c & -3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3
\end{pmatrix}=0.
$$
This has two independent solutions, iff the above matrix has rank 1, which is iff $a=0$.

Comment: Exactly I would add that you need to check whether there are two different eigenvectors to the eigenvalue $2$ because there is a theorem which says that a matrix is diagonalizable iff the sum of the dimension of the eigenspaces is equal to the dimension of the matrix

Comment: thanks. how do we know  dim of  space that equation for $\lambda_3=-1$ generated is 2?

Answer (score 2):

A matrix is diagonalisable if and only if its minimal polynomial is the product of distinct factors. Since the characteristic polynomial is $(x-2)^2(x+1)$, we see that $A$ is diagonalisable if and only if the polynomial $(x-2)(x+1)$ is the minimal polynomial.

Calculating this we get

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0&0&0 \\
a&0&0\\
b&c&-3\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
3&0&0 \\
a&3&0\\
b&c&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
0&0&0 \\
3a&0&0\\
ac&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And this is the zero matrix of and only if $a=0$.